# HTML5 Mp3 плеер

Tags: jquery, php, html5

В данный момент я занимаюсь разработкой музыкального сервиса. Сейчас мне нужен аудио плеер для воспроизведения mp3. Например, Grooveshark.com или z-music.org. Как можно реализовать такой же? Буду рад выслушать Ваши предложения.

Comment: http://jplayer.org/
http://ilyabirman.ru/projects/jouele/

Comment: Выбирайте: http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-awesome-html5-audio-players

Или пишите свой: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/HTML/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_HTML5_audio_and_video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Flash**. HTML5 audio — сыроват, а иногда может приводить к зависанию компьютера (в Chrome).

z-music.org, pleer.com (prostopleer.com) и подобные — используют [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/), чего и вам советую.

Comment: Спасибо, будем пробовать.